# Dovecot error connecting through Interspire email Marketer

Tags: dovecot

I am trying to setup the Bounce feature of Interspire Email Marketer (IEM) setup on a VPS (VPS 1), and am getting the following error. Im not a developer so dont understand whats happening.

I moved IEM to a new server with same settings as well as reinstalling a new Mailserver with dovecot.

The IEM settings for bounce email uses the POP3 Account and Autodetect Settings as it did previously but on the Dovecot server (VPS 2)... I am getting the following errors every time I try to test the bounce settings:

```
Sep 12 16:06:01 mail dovecot: pop3-login: Disconnected: Connection closed (no auth attempts in 0 secs): user=<>, rip=XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX, lip=YYY.YYY.YYY.YYY, session=<SkWEnisFkJyiE0K4>

Sep 12 16:06:01 mail dovecot: pop3-login: Disconnected: Connection closed (no auth attempts in 0 secs): user=<>, rip=XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX, lip=YYY.YYY.YYY.YYY, TLS handshaking: Connection closed, session=<4VuEnisFkpyiE0K4>

Sep 12 16:06:01 mail dovecot: pop3-login: Disconnected: Connection closed (no auth attempts in 0 secs): user=<>, rip=XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX, lip=YYY.YYY.YYY.YYY, TLS handshaking: Connection closed, session=<dayHnisFmJyiE0K4>

Sep 12 16:06:01 mail dovecot: pop3-login: Disconnected: Connection closed (no auth attempts in 0 secs): user=<>, rip=XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX, lip=YYY.YYY.YYY.YYY, TLS handshaking: Connection closed, session=<0SCLnisFopyiE0K4>

Sep 12 16:06:02 mail dovecot: pop3-login: Disconnected: Connection closed (no auth attempts in 0 secs): user=<>, rip=XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX, lip=YYY.YYY.YYY.YYY, TLS handshaking: Connection closed, session=<8aCOnisFsJyiE0K4>

Sep 12 16:06:02 mail dovecot: pop3-login: Disconnected: Aborted login by logging out (no auth attempts in 0 secs): user=<>, rip=XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX, lip=YYY.YYY.YYY.YYY, session=<agWSnisFtpyiE0K4>

Sep 12 16:06:02 mail dovecot: pop3-login: Disconnected: Aborted login by logging out (no auth attempts in 0 secs): user=<>, rip=XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX, lip=YYY.YYY.YYY.YYY, session=<V0eVnisFvpyiE0K4>

Sep 12 16:06:02 mail dovecot: pop3-login: Disconnected: Disconnected: Too many bad commands (no auth attempts in 0 secs): user=<>, rip=XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX, lip=YYY.YYY.YYY.YYY, session=<V6qYnisFwJyiE0K4>

Sep 12 16:06:03 mail dovecot: pop3-login: Disconnected: Disconnected: Too many bad commands (no auth attempts in 0 secs): user=<>, rip=XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX, lip=YYY.YYY.YYY.YYY, session=<zBOcnisFxpyiE0K4>

Sep 12 16:06:03 mail dovecot: pop3-login: Disconnected: Disconnected: Too many bad commands (no auth attempts in 0 secs): user=<>, rip=XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX, lip=YYY.YYY.YYY.YYY, session=<2sWlnisF0JyiE0K4>

Sep 12 16:06:03 mail dovecot: pop3-login: Disconnected: Disconnected: Too many bad commands (no auth attempts in 0 secs): user=<>, rip=XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX, lip=YYY.YYY.YYY.YYY, session=<nxupnisF4JyiE0K4>

Sep 12 16:06:05 mail dovecot: pop3-login: Disconnected: Connection closed (no auth attempts in 0 secs): user=<>, rip=XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX, lip=YYY.YYY.YYY.YYY, TLS handshaking: Connection closed, session=<Oqi/nisF8JyiE0K4>
```

I have changeed a few things in the dovecot config but nothing I wasnt told to do when installing the mail server.

Anyone have any ideas of what could the issue be? Thanks in appreciation.

Oh by the way, iredmail/dovecot/postfix are other wise working fine.

```
# More details about Dovecot settings: https://doc.dovecot.org

# Listen addresses.
#   - '*' means all available IPv4 addresses.
#   - '[::]' means all available IPv6 addresses.
# Listen on all available addresses by default
listen = * [::]

#base_dir = /var/run/dovecot
mail_plugins = quota mailbox_alias acl mail_log notify

# Enabled mail protocols.
protocols = pop3 imap sieve lmtp

# User/group who owns the message files:
mail_uid = 2000
mail_gid = 2000

# Assign uid to virtual users.
first_valid_uid = 2000
last_valid_uid = 2000

# Logging. Reference: http://wiki2.dovecot.org/Logging
#
# Use syslog
syslog_facility = local5

# Debug
#mail_debug = yes
#auth_verbose = yes
#auth_debug = yes
#auth_debug_passwords = yes

# Possible values: no, yes, plain, sha1.
# Set to 'yes' or 'plain', to output plaintext password (NOT RECOMMENDED).
#auth_verbose_passwords = no

# SSL: Global settings.
# Refer to wiki site for per protocol, ip, server name SSL settings:
# http://wiki2.dovecot.org/SSL/DovecotConfiguration
ssl_min_protocol = TLSv1.2
#ssl_protocols = !SSLv3
ssl = required
verbose_ssl = no
#ssl_ca = </path/to/ca
#ssl_cert = </etc/ssl/certs/iRedMail.crt
#ssl_key = </etc/ssl/private/iRedMail.key
ssl_cert = </etc/letsencrypt/live/mymaildomain.com/fullchain.pem
ssl_key = </etc/letsencrypt/live/mymaildomain.com/privkey.pem

ssl_dh = </etc/ssl/dh2048_param.pem

# Fix 'The Logjam Attack'
#ssl_cipher_list = EECDH+CHACHA20:EECDH+AESGCM:EDH+AESGCM:AES256+EECDH
ssl_cipher_list = ECDH+AESGCM:DH+AESGCM:ECDH+AES256:DH+AES256:ECDH+AES128:DH+AES:ECDH+3DES:DH+3DES:RSA+AESGCM:RSA+AES:RSA+3DES:!aNULL:!MD5

ssl_prefer_server_ciphers = yes

# With disable_plaintext_auth=yes AND ssl=required, STARTTLS is mandatory.
# Set disable_plaintext_auth=no AND ssl=yes to allow plain password transmitted
# insecurely.
disable_plaintext_auth = yes

# Allow plain text password per IP address/net
#remote 192.168.0.0/24 {
#   disable_plaintext_auth = no
#}

# Mail location and mailbox format.
mail_location = maildir:%Lh/Maildir/:INDEX=%Lh/Maildir/

# Authentication related settings.
# Append this domain name if client gives empty realm.
#auth_default_realm = 4elife.net

# Authentication mechanisms.
auth_mechanisms = PLAIN LOGIN

# Limits the number of users that can be logging in at the same time.
# Default is 100. This can be overridden by `process_limit =` in
# `service [protocol]` block.
# e.g.
#       protocol imap-login {
#           ...
#           process_limit = 500
#       }
#default_process_limit = 100

# Login log elements.
# Add '%k' for detailed SSL protocol and cipher information.
# e.g. "TLSv1.2 with cipher ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384 (256/256 bits)"
login_log_format_elements = user=<%u> method=%m rip=%r lip=%l mpid=%e %c %k session=<%{session}>

# Mail delivery log format
deliver_log_format = from=%{from}, envelope_sender=%{from_envelope}, subject=%{subject}, msgid=%m, size=%{size}, delivery_time=%{delivery_time}ms, %$

service auth {
    unix_listener /var/spool/postfix/private/dovecot-auth {
        user = postfix
        group = postfix
        mode = 0666
    }
    unix_listener auth-master {
        user = vmail
        group = vmail
        mode = 0666
    }
    unix_listener auth-userdb {
        user = vmail
        group = vmail
        mode = 0660
    }
}

# LMTP server (Local Mail Transfer Protocol).
# Reference: http://wiki2.dovecot.org/LMTP
service lmtp {
    user = vmail

    # For higher volume sites, it may be desirable to increase the number of
    # active listener processes. A range of 5 to 20 is probably good for most
    # sites.
    process_min_avail = 5

    # Logging.
    executable = lmtp -L

    # Listening on socket file and TCP
    unix_listener /var/spool/postfix/private/dovecot-lmtp {
        user = postfix
        group = postfix
        mode = 0600
    }

    inet_listener lmtp {
        # Listen on localhost (ipv4)
        address = 127.0.0.1
        port = 24
    }
}

# Virtual mail accounts.
userdb {
    args = /etc/dovecot/dovecot-mysql.conf
    driver = sql
}
passdb {
    args = /etc/dovecot/dovecot-mysql.conf
    driver = sql
}

# Master user.
# Master users are able to log in as other users. It's also possible to
# directly log in as any user using a master password, although this isn't
# recommended.
# Reference: http://wiki2.dovecot.org/Authentication/MasterUsers
auth_master_user_separator = *
passdb {
    driver = passwd-file
    args = /etc/dovecot/dovecot-master-users
    master = yes
}

plugin {
    # Quota configuration.
    # Reference: http://wiki2.dovecot.org/Quota/Configuration
    quota = dict:user::proxy::quotadict

    # Set default quota rule if no quota returned from SQL/LDAP query.
    #quota_rule = *:storage=1G
    #quota_rule2 = *:messages=0
    #quota_rule3 = Trash:storage=1G
    #quota_rule4 = Junk:ignore

    # Quota warning.
    #
    # If user suddenly receives a huge mail and the quota jumps from
    # 85% to 95%, only the 95% script is executed.
    #
    # Only the command for the first exceeded limit is executed, so configure
    # the highest limit first.
    quota_warning = storage=100%% quota-warning 100 %u
    quota_warning2 = storage=95%% quota-warning 95 %u
    quota_warning3 = storage=90%% quota-warning 90 %u
    quota_warning4 = storage=85%% quota-warning 85 %u

    # allow user to become max 10% (or 50 MB) over quota
    quota_grace = 10%%
    #quota_grace = 50 M

    # Custom Quota Exceeded Message.
    # You can specify the message directly or read the message from a file.
    #quota_exceeded_message = Quota exceeded, please try again later.
    #quota_exceeded_message = </path/to/quota_exceeded_message.txt

    # Used by quota-status service.
    quota_status_success = DUNNO
    quota_status_nouser = DUNNO
    quota_status_overquota = "552 5.2.2 Mailbox is full"

    # ACL and share folder
    acl = vfile
    acl_shared_dict = proxy::acl

    # By default Dovecot doesn't allow using the IMAP "anyone" or
    # "authenticated" identifier, because it would be an easy way to spam
    # other users in the system. If you wish to allow it,
    #acl_anyone = allow

    # Pigeonhole managesieve service.
    # Reference: http://wiki2.dovecot.org/Pigeonhole/Sieve/Configuration
    # Per-user sieve settings.
    sieve_dir = ~/sieve
    sieve = ~/sieve/dovecot.sieve

    # Global sieve settings.
    sieve_global_dir = /var/vmail/sieve
    # Note: if user has personal sieve script, global sieve rules defined in
    #       sieve_default will be ignored. Please use sieve_before or
    #       sieve_after instead.
    #sieve_default =

    sieve_before = /var/vmail/sieve/dovecot.sieve
    #sieve_after =

    # The maximum number of redirect actions that can be performed during a
    # single script execution.
    # The meaning of 0 differs based on your version. For pigeonhole-0.3.0 and
    # beyond this means that redirect is prohibited. For older versions,
    # however, this means that the number of redirects is unlimited.
    sieve_max_redirects = 30

    # Use recipient as vacation message sender instead of null sender (<>).
    sieve_vacation_send_from_recipient = yes

    # Reference: http://wiki2.dovecot.org/Plugins/MailboxAlias
    mailbox_alias_old = Sent
    mailbox_alias_new = Sent Messages
    mailbox_alias_old2 = Sent
    mailbox_alias_new2 = Sent Items

    # Events to log. `autoexpunge` is included in `expunge`
    # Defined in https://github.com/dovecot/core/blob/master/src/plugins/mail-log/mail-log-plugin.c
    mail_log_events = delete undelete expunge copy mailbox_create mailbox_delete mailbox_rename
    mail_log_fields = uid box msgid size from subject flags

    # Track user last login
    last_login_dict = proxy::lastlogin
    last_login_key = last-login/%s/%u/%d
}

service stats {
    fifo_listener stats-mail {
        user = vmail
        mode = 0644
    }

    unix_listener stats-writer {
        user = vmail
        group = vmail
        mode = 0660
    }

    inet_listener {
        address = 127.0.0.1
        port = 24242
    }
}

service quota-warning {
    executable = script /usr/local/bin/dovecot-quota-warning.sh
    unix_listener quota-warning {
        user = vmail
        group = vmail
        mode = 0660
    }
}

service quota-status {
    # '-p <protocol>'. Currently only 'postfix' protocol is supported.
    executable = quota-status -p postfix
    client_limit = 1
    inet_listener {
        address = 127.0.0.1
        port = 12340
    }
}

service dict {
    unix_listener dict {
        mode = 0660
        user = vmail
        group = vmail
    }
}

dict {
    quotadict = mysql:/etc/dovecot/dovecot-used-quota.conf
    acl = mysql:/etc/dovecot/dovecot-share-folder.conf
    lastlogin = mysql:/etc/dovecot/dovecot-last-login.conf
}

protocol lda {
    mail_plugins = $mail_plugins sieve
    lda_mailbox_autocreate = yes
    lda_mailbox_autosubscribe = yes
}

protocol lmtp {
    # Plugins
    mail_plugins = $mail_plugins sieve

    # Address extension delivery
    lmtp_save_to_detail_mailbox = yes
    recipient_delimiter = +
}

protocol imap {
    mail_plugins = $mail_plugins imap_quota imap_acl last_login
    imap_client_workarounds = tb-extra-mailbox-sep

    # Maximum number of IMAP connections allowed for a user from each IP address.
    # NOTE: The username is compared case-sensitively.
    # Default is 10.
    # Increase it to avoid issue like below:
    # "Maximum number of concurrent IMAP connections exceeded"
    mail_max_userip_connections = 30
}

protocol pop3 {
    mail_plugins = $mail_plugins last_login
    pop3_client_workarounds = outlook-no-nuls oe-ns-eoh
    pop3_uidl_format = %08Xu%08Xv

    # Maximum number of IMAP connections allowed for a user from each IP address.
    # NOTE: The username is compared case-sensitively.
    # Default is 10.
    mail_max_userip_connections = 30

    # POP3 logout format string:
    #  %i - total number of bytes read from client
    #  %o - total number of bytes sent to client
    #  %t - number of TOP commands
    #  %p - number of bytes sent to client as a result of TOP command
    #  %r - number of RETR commands
    #  %b - number of bytes sent to client as a result of RETR command
    #  %d - number of deleted messages
    #  %m - number of messages (before deletion)
    #  %s - mailbox size in bytes (before deletion)
    # Default format doesn't have 'in=%i, out=%o'.
    #pop3_logout_format = top=%t/%p, retr=%r/%b, del=%d/%m, size=%s, in=%i, out=%o
}

# Login processes. Refer to Dovecot wiki for more details:
# http://wiki2.dovecot.org/LoginProcess
service imap-login {
    #inet_listener imap {
    #    port = 143
    #}
    #inet_listener imaps {
    #    port = 993
    #    ssl = yes
    #}

    service_count = 1

    # To avoid startup latency for new client connections, set process_min_avail
    # to higher than zero. That many idling processes are always kept around
    # waiting for new connections.
    #process_min_avail = 0

    # number of simultaneous IMAP connections
    process_limit = 800

    # vsz_limit should be fine at its default 64MB value
    #vsz_limit = 64M
}

service pop3-login {
    #inet_listener pop3 {
    #    port = 110
    #}
    #inet_listener pop3s {
    #    port = 995
    #    ssl = yes
    #}

    service_count = 1

    # number of simultaneous POP3 connections
    #process_limit = 500
}

service managesieve-login {
    inet_listener sieve {
        # Listen on localhost (ipv4)
        address = 127.0.0.1
        port = 4190
    }
}

namespace {
    type = private
    separator = /
    prefix =
    inbox = yes

    # Refer to document for more details about alias mailbox:
    # http://wiki2.dovecot.org/MailboxSettings
    #
    # Sent
    mailbox Sent {
        auto = subscribe
        special_use = \Sent
    }
    mailbox "Sent Messages" {
        auto = no
        special_use = \Sent
    }
    mailbox "Sent Items" {
        auto = no
        special_use = \Sent
    }

    mailbox Drafts {
        auto = subscribe
        special_use = \Drafts
    }

    # Trash
    mailbox Trash {
        auto = subscribe
        special_use = \Trash
    }

    mailbox "Deleted Messages" {
        auto = no
        special_use = \Trash
    }

    # Junk
    mailbox Junk {
        auto = subscribe
        special_use = \Junk
    }
    mailbox Spam {
        auto = no
        special_use = \Junk
    }
    mailbox "Junk E-mail" {
        auto = no
        special_use = \Junk
    }

    # Archive
    mailbox Archive {
        auto = no
        special_use = \Archive
    }
    mailbox Archives {
        auto = no
        special_use = \Archive
    }
}

namespace {
    type = shared
    separator = /
    prefix = Shared/%%u/
    location = maildir:%%Lh/Maildir/:INDEX=%%Lh/Maildir/Shared/%%Ld/%%Ln

    # this namespace should handle its own subscriptions or not.
    subscriptions = yes
    list = children
}

# Public mailboxes.
# Refer to Dovecot wiki page for more details:
# http://wiki2.dovecot.org/SharedMailboxes/Public
#namespace {
#    type = public
#    separator = /
#    prefix = Public/
#    location = maildir:/var/vmail/public:CONTROL=%Lh/Maildir/public:INDEXPVT=%Lh/Maildir/public
#
#    # Allow users to subscribe to the public folders.
#    subscriptions = yes
#}

!include_try /etc/dovecot/iredmail/*.conf
```